# How To: Change Block Text Color

Tags: 7, blocks

I need to change the text color of a block on my main page.  The existing theme uses blue text on a light blue background which makes it somewhat difficult to read.  I used Firebug to find the div ID and created a local.css file per [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/728920).

```
#block-views-team-events-calendar-block-2 .content
{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

I changed the color to white, but, I don't see any change on the page.  I tried clearing the cache, but, I got the same results.  How can I change the text color for one single block on my main page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons why your styles are not applied to the page elements:

- **CSS aggregation is enabled.** Disable aggregation and see if your custom CSS works. If it doesn't, you probably forgot to include the file in your theme - move to the next option.
- **CSS stylesheet is not added to the theme via THEMENAME.info file or other methods**. Placement of the CSS file in your theme's css folder does not make it load while Drupal pages are loading.
- **wrong selector used**
- **styles are overridden by a selector with higher specificity**  ...etc.

To add CSS stylesheet to the Drupal theme, add the following to the current theme's .info file and clear cache:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/local.css
```

You can also add CSS files to your theme via [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) function that you can use in `hook_preprocess_page()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  My problem was resolved by updating the theme's info file as you suggested.